# Textarea for comments in Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, layout

I try to implement a modul, which adds a textarea at the end of the checkoutprocess in "Order Review", but the textarea is nowhere to be seen, when i enable the "Template Path Hints"-Debugoption, i can see that it load my customized .phtml file, but there isnt a textarea.

Setupscript works fine

"Terms and Conditions" are enabled

Module is enabled

Here is the code:

**app/code/local/Practice/CheckoutComments/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Practice_CheckoutComments>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Practice_CheckoutComments>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <resources>
            <checkoutcomments_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Practice_CheckoutComments</module>
                </setup>
            </checkoutcomments_setup>
        </resources>
        <models>
            <checkoutcomments>
                <class>Practice_CheckoutComments_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>checkoutcomments_resource</resourceModel>
            </checkoutcomments>

            <checkoutcomments_resource>
                <class>Practice_CheckoutComments_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <comments_table>
                        <table>checkout_comments</table>
                    </comments_table>
                </entities>
            </checkoutcomments_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <checkoutcomments>
                    <file>practice/checkoutcomments.xml</file>
                </checkoutcomments>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/practice/checkoutcomments.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <checkout_onepage_review translate="label">
        <reference name="checkout.onepage.agreements">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>practice/checkoutcomments/onepage/comment-agreements.phtml
                </template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_review>
</layout>
```

**app/design/frontend/base/default/template/practice/checkoutcomments/onepage/comment-agreements.phtml**

```
<!--  Start of CheckoutComments module code -->

<form action="" id="checkout-agreements" onsubmit="return false;">
        <ol class="checkout-agreements">
        <div>
            <br /><label for="checkoutcomments"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->__('Add your Comment for this Order') ?></label>
            <textarea name="checkoutcomments" id="checkoutcomments"
                style="width: 450px; height: 100px;"></textarea>
        </div>

<?php if ($this->getAgreements()) : ?>
        <!-- End of CheckoutComment module -->


<?php foreach ($this->getAgreements() as $_a): ?>
    <li>
            <div class="agreement-content"
                <?php echo ($_a->getContentHeight() ? ' style="height:' . $_a->getContentHeight() . '"' : '')?>>
            <?php if ($_a->getIsHtml()):?>
                <?php echo $_a->getContent()?>
            <?php else:?>
                <?php echo nl2br($this->escapeHtml($_a->getContent()))?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
            <p class="agree">
                <input type="checkbox" id="agreement-<?php echo $_a->getId()?>"
                    name="agreement[<?php echo $_a->getId()?>]" value="1"
                    title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_a->getCheckboxText()) ?>"
                    class="checkbox" /><label for="agreement-<?php echo $_a->getId()?>"><?php echo $_a->getIsHtml() ? $_a->getCheckboxText() : $this->escapeHtml($_a->getCheckboxText()) ?></label>
            </p>
        </li>
<?php endforeach ?>

<?php endif; ?>

</ol>

</form>
```

Comment: Is the rest of the form rendering?

Comment: here is Roland again (i forgot my password and i'm on a different computer right now) Yes,besides the first lines and the last line > `<?php endif; ?>` everything else is copied from the checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml

Answer (score 2):

You want to know whether your layout.xml file is loaded:

1. Turn on Developer mode
2. make a typo in your layout.xml
3. clear cache
4. there should be an error. If there is no error, your layout.xml **is not loaded**

You want to know whether your template is set:

1. Install xdebug
2. check whether the `setTemplate` method is called on the right block

Make sure nothing else changes your template!

Answer (score 0):

The Textarea html code should be inside `<li>` tag